# What's the fastest way to find files which matches a specified criteria?

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems, ext4

```
OS: Linux
File System: ext4
Programming Language: C/C++
```

Assume that you've 10 million files in a folder each of which is in format:

```
StartTimestamp-EndTimestamp.ext
```

We know that EndTimestamp is greater than StartTimestamp. We may also "force" them not to have any intersection. I mean that they may be forced to have sequentional timestamps like this:

```
0001-0100.ext
0102-0154.ext
0178-0236.ext
0236-0343.ext
...
```

and don't be like this:

```
0002-0200.ext
0050-0150.ext
0120-0220.ext
...
```

In another words, at a specified timestamp we may be forced to have only one match, if it may help. 
I'm looking for the fastest method to find the file(s) which match the specified timestamp like this:

```
0100 --> 0001-0100.ext
0101 --> no match
0102 --> 0102-0154.ext
0150 --> 0102-0154.ext
```

and if it can't help and we're not forced to avoid intersection between files:

```
0100 --> 0002-0200.ext, 0050-0150.ext
0200 --> 0002-0200.ext, 0120-0220.ext
```

For simplicity I reduced number of digits of a timestamp to 4. It's indeed 16 digits. My question is indeed: How to RANDOMLY access and find the file I want without need (or by least need) to use glob or readdir or such functions? We know that in a journal file system, files are stored in BTree indexed structure format. I need to use this without having to walk on them.

Comment: Fastest way, both in development time, and actual performance,  is to build a real database and search in there without interacting with filesystem at all until the very last moment - when you found the file.

Comment: *Assume that you've 10 million files in a folder*  Fastest?  Start from an actual sane design.

Comment: AFAIK there's no filesystem API for Linux that provides any way to search for this quickly. All you can do is sequential search, which will be really slow with 10 million files in a single folder. If you can't use a real DB, you could try grouping the files into subdirectories with a common prefix.

Comment: Indeed a db is currently used. We're going to avoid out of sync records and a folder itself be enough.

Comment: is there a daemon process involved? Itf it's so it should be possible to read the directory once and then use the [inotify API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to get informed by changes. But I have not used it yet, so I'm not sure

Comment: No, there's no daemon process involved. We use mysql to find the record, but the queries sometimes gets so heavy. Getting out of sync (db records and files) is another reason I'm thinking about changing the algorithm.

Comment: *We know that in a journal file system, files are stored in BTree indexed structure format* uh? You know that some of use BTree...

Comment: Whichever process created 10 million files in the same directory, it's hopelessly flawed. "Doctor, it hurts when I move my arm this way." -- "Well, stop moving your arm that way! Next patient, please..." The solution here is to manage files in a sane directory structure. There are git repositories with millions of files. They're not in the same directory, you know.

Comment: Even if you know that BTree are used, it is internal structure and you don't have access to. Filesystems API only gives you sequential reading on directories. They are not intended to be used as DB-for-the-poor.

Comment: They're output of a video surveillance application like ZoneMinder. Each camera stored its records in a separate folder.

Comment: You mean for having a random access to these files using DB is inevitable?